# Jabber multiple JID in one account

Tags: xmpp, prosody-im

maybe anyone know solution.

I have multiple JID.

```
user@domain.com
user@domain2.com
user@domain3.com
```

15 JID, on public servers, and also have own jabber(prosody server)
can i split all that JID to one ?

Now i use PSI with multiple accounts, but I would like to use one and the other to forward messages to it.
And that the answer was from the account in which they wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You may use xmpp-2-xmpp transport. It connects the other XMPP account(s) in your name and forwards (proxies) all messages etc.

There are two implementations that I am aware of:

- J2J: http://wiki.jrudevels.org/Eng:J2J
- Spectrum: http://spectrum.im (with Libpurple Jabber backend)

Unfortunately if you need to connect multiple accounts, you will need to set up multiple transport instances, as one transport instance allows only one registration per user.